# Cardinal inequality

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Given infinite cardinal numbers $\mathfrak{m<n}$, is it true that $2^\mathfrak{m}<2^\mathfrak{n}$?

Comment: That's independent of ZFC

Comment: This is definitely a dupe: I've seen Asaf answer this several times.

Comment: As per @AlessandroCodenotti's comment, see the fourth bullet point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_independent_of_ZFC#Axiomatic_set_theory) (sadly, with no reference). See also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/6594/118109) answer. For a proof, see [Jech 2003](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540440857).